# Does a capacitor discharge and recharge in a loop while power is going through it? or only when power is cut off?

Tags: capacitor

Beginner Question. I'm trying to understand how a simple LED flashing circuit works, here is a picture of the circuit:

[image]

I know that much like a Relay, a Transistor could be used as a switch by using it's base and passing a small amount of power to it.

Now something needs to `Connect and Disconnect` the power to the transistor to make it work as an `automatic switch` or the LED will not flash and remain On.

In the picture above, what is taking care of that power oscillation? is it the Capacitor? Does a capacitor discharge and recharge in a loop or only when its cut off power? if not then what does the capacitor do here?

Comment: please provide the schematic diagram .... please refer to the pins using the correct terms (collector, emitter, base) .... do not refer to them as "middle pin", etc.  .... not all transistors have the same pinout

Comment: here is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPbiplBq7Z4

Comment: That circuit works on avalanche breakdown of the transistor, which is a topic that is more advanced than you’ll want to start with. Charles Wenzel has a [hobby circuits page](http://www.techlib.com/electronics/flasher.html) with some simple flasher circuits, and he provides nice descriptions of how they work. You might give some of those a try.

Comment: Thank you, could answer this, does the capacitor keep its charge the whole time its plugged in? it does not discharge until its cut off power?

Comment: No, when the charge on the capacitor gets large enough to trigger the avalanche, it is discharged through the LED.

Comment: what exactly are you asking here? `keep its charge the whole time`

Comment: What I'm asking is, assume capacitor is plugged and now it's charged. Does it let go of its charge and recharge itself again on a constant loop, or it keep its charge and only discharges when unplugged form power.

Comment: The capacitor does charge and discharge each time the LED flashes. But see my comment below -- this is a very unusual circuit and not suitable for a beginner to learn about transistors. It's sort of a "trick circuit".

Comment: generically speaking tho, no specifically in this circuit, does it charge and discharge?

Comment: In general, no, it will not do that on its own.

Comment: @Josepha Try read this https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/338838/bootstrap-capacitor-explanation/338843#338843 and this https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/capacitors-how-do-they-work.80390/#post-570788

Answer (score 2):

This circuit is a negative resistance transistor oscillator. It's kind of a gimmicky circuit for a beginner, it is a very unusual use of a transistor, and is not actually using the transistor as a switch in the usual way at all. (You can tell that this is the case because the base of the transistor is not connected to anything, which is normally necessary to use it as a switch.)

See this video for some more discussion of what's happening: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rpGOKGrcpAk

"Negative resistance" (more properly "negative differential resistance") is a property that some electronic components have, including certain transistors when used in a reverse-biased way. (You can read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_resistance#Negative_differential_resistance ) It describes a region of the I-V curve (the curve that describes a device's resistance, or how its current and voltage relate to each other in a circuit) where the current *decreases* as the voltage *increases* and vice versa, which is the reverse of the usual relationship for a passive component. I call the circuit 'gimmicky' in part because most of the cheap transistors that do this are not explicitly designed or specified to behave this way -- they happen to do it, but it's not guaranteed to work and might vary with things like temperature, or what batch your transistor happens to be from.

The capacitor does charge and discharge in a loop along with the flashing of the LED. The capacitor can't do that by itself -- the unusual property of the transistor is what triggers it to start and stop charging.

I would not recommend this circuit as an example to learn from, when learning about the use of transistors in basic electronics! It's a very cute gimmick but that's really all it is.

Comment: thank you, can you point me to a better LED flash circuit? also generically speaking (not in this circuit) does a capacitor keep its charge the whole time its plugged in? it does not discharge until its cut off power?

Comment: The capacitor charges and discharges each time through the loop.

For some simple LED flasher circuits, see this page, from the old Nuts & Volts Magazine: http://www.nutsvolts.com/magazine/article/practical-led-indicator-and-flasher-circuits

Scroll down to the section titled "LED Flasher Circuits" (or read the rest too, it's useful and interesting!) The very first design is a good example of a simple LED flasher using only transistors, resistors, and capacitors. Many of the other circuits use the 555 timer chip, which is simpler than it looks at first, but might be unsatisfying.

Comment: So If I use a capacitor in a circuit (other than flashing LEDs), it will charge and discharge in a loop? why would that be helpful, isn't it similar to plugging and unplugging the circuit from power?

Comment: A capacitor can do any number of different things depending on the circuit. In this circuit, the transistor is used to make the capacitor charge and discharge in a loop. The capacitor won't do that by itself.

Answer (score 1):

This trick circuit uses a failure mode of Vce reverse voltage > -5V to conduct up to 5mA at some threshold then go into Avalanche mode and discharge the capacitor to near -5V when the holding current of this negative resistance latch like an SCR, goes out of -Rs mode and into a +Rs mode  and allows the cap to charge up again. -Rs means the voltage drops abruptly as the current rises. +Rs mode means it acts like resistance great than -5V when overstressed with reverse voltage.

Thus it forms an Relaxation Oscillator where the LED draws current from the 1k and thru the Vec which has some resistance like a zener great than at the same time charging up the cap until the DIAC-like condition triggers again.

The LED series R must not exceed the 5mA tigger current much as the energy discharge from the capacitor can burn out the Vec junction.  So it works but with some unspecified stress and reduced life span.